# Bourbon not importing correctly?

Tags: ruby, sass, rubygems

I am trying to use Bourbon, Bitters & Neat. However, I get en error when I import them.

The error is:

```
Error: Undefined variable: "$font-stack-system".
  on line 6 of base/_variables.scss
  from line 6 of base/_base.scss
  from line 2 of base.sass
```

File structure:
  sass/base (bitters)/ *content of biitters is here*

sass/bourbon/*content here*

sass/neat/*content here*

base.sass is the file that I am importing bourbon etc into.

base.sass is located in sass/base.sass

Any help?

They are installed via ruby gems.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the [issues page](https://github.com/thoughtbot/bitters/search?q=font-stack-system&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93) on GitHub? Several people seem to have had this issue, and there is lots of discussion around resolving it. What have you tried so far? What gem versions are you using?

Comment: At a glance, it seems like `Bitters 1.3` requires `Bourbon 5.0`. You could either downgrade `Bitters` or upgrade `Bourbon`. Does that solve your problem? (If so, I'll write this as an answer below.)

Answer (score 0):

Just make some changes in base folders that gets created after you install bitters. Goto _variable.scss
copy and paste the following code under //Typography

```
// Typography

$sans-serif: $monospace;
$serif: $georgia;

$base-font-family: $sans-serif;
$heading-font-family: $base-font-family;
```